# Upload a large file into Shared Folder through Microsoft Graph API app only asp.net Access Denied

Tags: asp.net, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following the example of the [aspnet-snippets-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/master/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/Models/FilesService.cs)
 and [OneDriveTest.cs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/commit/7c037cf15413b73d1ad7b52ee027a703f4b63be1#diff-73f67618397ff61d1687ddfa1ce6ae91) to upload a large file through the Microsoft Graph API into a shared folder with app only credentials

and following exception is thrown:

"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

To initialize a large file upload session I do following:

```
var uploadSession = await _graph
                           .Drives[DRIVEID]
                           .Items[ITEMID]
                           .ItemWithPath("newFile.docx")
                           .CreateUploadSession()
                           .Request().PostAsync();
```

Both the driveId and itemId are valid.

I'm creating my GraphClient like following:

```
public MicrosoftGraphHelper()
        {

            _graph = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", AccessToken);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }));

        }
```

The access token is acquired through my app credentials and secret. In Azure, my app has read/write permissions for files through Microsoft Graph.

Also, creating a new folder like

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/DRIVEID/items/ITEMID/children
```

with JSON

```
{
  "name": "NewFolderTest",
  "folder": { }
}
```

works as well.

here is the Upload Task

```
internal async Task<string> UploadLargeFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {


                using (Stream fileStream = file.InputStream)
                {
                    // Create the upload session. The access token is no longer required as you have session established for the upload.  
                    // POST /v1.0/drive/root:/UploadLargeFile.bmp:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession

                    var driveItems = await _graph.Drives[DRIVEID]
                           .Items[ITEMID]
                           .Children
                           .Request()
                           .GetAsync();

                    var uploadSession = await _graph.Drives[DRIVEID]
                        .Items[ITEMID].ItemWithPath("test.docx").CreateUploadSession()
                        .Request().PostAsync();

                    var maxChunkSize = 320 * 1024; // 320 KB - Change this to your chunk size. 5MB is the default.
                    var provider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(uploadSession, _graph, fileStream, maxChunkSize);

                    // Setup the chunk request necessities
                    var chunkRequests = provider.GetUploadChunkRequests();
                    var readBuffer = new byte[maxChunkSize];
                    var trackedExceptions = new List<Exception>();
                    DriveItem itemResult = null;

                    //upload the chunks
                    foreach (var request in chunkRequests)
                    {
                        // Do your updates here: update progress bar, etc.
                        // ...
                        // Send chunk request
                        var result = await provider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, readBuffer, trackedExceptions);

                        if (result.UploadSucceeded)
                        {
                            itemResult = result.ItemResponse;
                        }
                    }

                    // Check that upload succeeded
                    if (itemResult == null)
                    {
                        // Retry the upload
                        // ...
                    }

                    return "Success";
                }

            }

            catch (ServiceException e)
            {
                // Debug.WriteLine("We could not upload the file: " + e.Error.Message);
                return null;
            }

        }
```

As soon as the code hits:

```
var result = await provider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, readBuffer, trackedExceptions);
```

trying to request:

```
"https://myapp.sharepoint.com:443/sites/dev/_api/v2.0/drives/DRIVEID/items/ITEMID/uploadSession"
```

is thrown.

What and where do I have to apply required permissions? The [Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession) refers to `Files.ReadWrite` Does Sharepoint need additional permissions to Microsoft Graph API?

Within the shared folder I can see a new created tmp file with 0 bytes.